# Organization-specific restrictions for multi-org users sharing the same email domain during SSO login in Auth0

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, auth0, okta, auth0-connection

Need help to configure Single Sign-On (SSO) for enterprise connections who manage multiple organizations using Auth0. Specifically, we need to ensure that users with the same email domain can be authenticated for a particular organization while restricting SSO access to other organizations—even if the user is a member of those additional organizations.

Example Scenario:
Consider a user with an email domain of 'abcxyz'.
This user is a member of both org1 and org2.
We aim to allow SSO login for org1 while requiring password-based authentication for org2.